# How rescue Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, mongoid

I use rails 3.2, mongoid 3, devise 2.2.4, passenger and nginx.

I got the error "We've sorry, but something went wrong" when my rails app can't find MongoDB. I want to change the error message to something more relevant to the error. For example: Failed to connect to Database.

I saw, that Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure was raised, but I can't rescue it in Application controller with rescue_from. It seems that error rised, when devise try to get user from session on initialization. Off :authenticate_user! can't help.

Answer (score 0):

Find the line where the error is occuring. Surround it with a `begin; rescue` block, like so:

`begin
  # code which raises the error
rescue Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure => e
  raise MyOwnError
end`

Of course you will need to define MyOwnError:

`class MyOwnError < StandardError; end`

Good luck. You might try Googling Ruby errors and exceptions.

Comment: It rises in warden. I don't want to monkey patch it.

Comment: There's something wrong in your code. Warden works. I use Sinatra, Padrino, and Rails, with Moped/Mongoid, and Warden, and I have no issues at all. Sounds like you have a connection problem from your application to your MongoDB.

Anyway your question was how to rescue the error and raise your own error with your own message, which I answered. What I recommended is not in any way a "monkey patch", it is simple Ruby.

Comment: BUT, I do remember recently a colleague had a similar issue with passenger/nginx + moped and could not get a connection. Have you tried running the code outside of passenger/nginx? See if it works without passenger/nginx.